# How to stop processing icon in kendo Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

$("#tankNameAutocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
       // refresh: false,

```
    dataBound: function(e) {
        if (e.minLength < 3) {
            var autoComplete = $("#tankNameAutocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");
            autoComplete.dataSource.data([]);
        }
    },
    dataTextField: "CustomerLocationAndTankName",
    suggest: true,
    select: tanknameautocomplete_select,
    filter: "startswith",
    dataSource: { serverFiltering: true, transport: { read: { url: "/InventoryList/GetTankNames/", dataType: "json", type: "GET" } } },        
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your Question is a little unclear right now. If you explain exactly what you expect your code snippet to do, and what it's actually doing, you'll be more likely to get good replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to hide the spinner icon that shows when server filtering is activate and prior to displaying the results. If this is the case you can overwrite it with CSS as in this example:

http://trykendoui.telerik.com/EjIR

Comment: $("#tankNameAutocomplete").keyup(function () {

Comment: $("#tankNameAutocomplete").keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length = 0) {
                if ($('#tankNameAutocomplete').next('span').hasClass('k-loading'))
                    $('#tankNameAutocomplete').next('span').hide();
            }
        });